# Azure Function with Event Hub Trigger - Can I change the Port Used to Retrieve Events?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-eventhub

My Azure function successfully retrieves eventhub events on a home network, but not from inside my company network. Error received as follows:

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond >after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host >has failed to respond

By default, the eventhub trigger uses AMQ protocol, which is blocked by our firewall.   I'd like to change the transport type to use https over port 443.

Code generated by Visual Studio 2022 (works fine from home network)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace EventHubConsumers
{
    public class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public async Task Run([EventHubTrigger("test1", Connection = "ConnectionToEventHubReceived")] EventData[] events, ILogger log)
       
        {
            var exceptions = new List<Exception>();
            foreach (EventData eventData in events)
            {
                try
                {
                    string messageBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(eventData.Body.Array, eventData.Body.Offset, eventData.Body.Count);

                    // Replace these two lines with your processing logic.
                    log.LogInformation($"C# Event Hub trigger function processed a message: {messageBody}");
                    await Task.Yield();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    // We need to keep processing the rest of the batch - capture this exception and continue.
                    // Also, consider capturing details of the message that failed processing so it can be processed again later.
                    exceptions.Add(e);
                }
            }

            // Once processing of the batch is complete, if any messages in the batch failed processing throw an exception so that there is a record of the failure.
            if (exceptions.Count > 1)
                throw new AggregateException(exceptions);
            if (exceptions.Count == 1)
                throw exceptions.Single();
        }
    }
}
```

How can I change the transport type?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

To use port 443, you'll need to change the transport option to `AmqpWebSockets`.

#### Update

The option to set the transport type is available as part of the host settings for `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventHubs` v5.0 and above; the documentation was outdated.

Transport-related settings can be specified using:

```json
{
  "extensions": {
    "eventHubs": {
      "transportType" : "amqpWebSockets",
      "webProxy" : "https://proxyserver:8080",
      "customEndpointAddress" : "amqps://company.gateway.local"            
  }
}
```

These should appear in the [settings documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs) in the near future. Until then, details about them can be found in the [EventHubOptions docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.webjobs.eventhubs.eventhuboptions?view=azure-dotnet).

#### Original Answer *(valid, but requires more effort)*

Unfortunately, this is not exposed in the [settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs).  You'll need to [create a startup class for the Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection), if you don't already have one, and configure DI to set the transport option when creating Event Hubs clients.

For example, a minimal implementation would look something like:

```cs
using Azure.Messaging.EventHubs;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;

[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(SomeNamespace.Startup))]

namespace SomeNamespace
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            var wjBuilder = builder.Services.AddWebJobs(_ => {});

            // This method allows you to mutate the options used to 
            // create the Event Hubs clients and set the transport.
            wjBuilder.AddEventHubs(options =>
            {
                options.TransportType = EventHubsTransportType.AmqpWebSockets;
            });  

            wjBuilder.AddBuiltInBindings();
            wjBuilder.AddExecutionContextBinding();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks very promising :)   Thanks for the links on DI for functions too!   Will give this a try later today.

Comment: I tried to upvote, but don't have enough history.   Much appreciated.   Your approach to use DI seems like the way to go if constrained to use the EventHubTrigger and firewall blocks the port/protocol.   A colleague suggested I use the EventHubConsumerClient which can be configured to listen on port 443 using https.   This is a bit easier to get running and solves my business problem.   Code below.

Comment: Glad to hear that you came up with an approach.   I left some feedback below.   To be pedantic, Event Hubs always communicates via AMQP.   You're setting the transport to use web sockets to route the communication, but it's not HTTP-based traffic.

Answer (score 0):

Getting events from an EventHub via Azure functions and HTTPS can also be solved with a Timer Trigger and the EventHubConsumerClient.   Note the options passed into its constructor to configure it for AmqpWebSockets.

````cs
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Azure.Messaging.EventHubs;
using Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Consumer;

namespace EventHubConsumerPOC
{
    public class Function1
    {

        private const string connectionStringTest1 = "Endpoint=sb://[[ REDACTED ]].servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=[[ REDACTED ]];SharedAccessKey=[[ REDACTED ]];EntityPath=[[ REDACTED ]]";
        private const string eventHubName1 = "[[ REDACTED ]]";
        private const string consumerGroup = "$Default";

        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public async Task RunAsync([TimerTrigger("0 * * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)  //every 1 minute
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");

            await GetTask(log);

        }

        private async Task GetTask(ILogger log)
        {
            var processorOptions = new EventHubConsumerClientOptions
            {
                ConnectionOptions = new EventHubConnectionOptions
                {
                    TransportType = EventHubsTransportType.AmqpWebSockets
                }
            };
            var consumerClient = new EventHubConsumerClient(consumerGroup, connectionStringTest1, processorOptions);

            await foreach (PartitionEvent _event in consumerClient.ReadEventsAsync())
            {
                log.LogInformation(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(_event.Data.EventBody));
            }
        }
    }
}```
````

Comment: Please be aware that you included sensitive information in the post, including your shared access key.   I've redacted it, but it will still be available in history to those who look.   Please consider the key compromised and roll them.

Comment: What's going to happen there is that you're going to create a new connection to Event Hubs for each invocation of your function.   Since you're not explicitly closing/disposing, that connection is going to leak and remain open until it times out after 20 minutes of idle time.    I'd strongly recommend that you either inject the client via the DI extensions (which will register it as a singleton and manage its lifetime) or hoist it up as a `static` so that it can be reused.